# Change count in Custom Tab with table according to filtered data

Tags: custom-fields, custom

I have filtered the data being shown in a custom group tab on contact page but I'm struggling on how to change the count being shown next to the tab name. Could anyone help me how? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you used a tabset hook to adapt the tab on the contact page. That is where you can influence the count as you can see here:

```
  $tabs[] = [
    'id' => "mediweattestbeheer",
    'url' => CRM_Utils_System::url("civicrm/mediweattestbeheer/page/mediweattest", "reset=1&mid=" . $contactId, TRUE),
    'title' => "Attesten",
    'weight' => 16,
    'count' => CRM_Mediweattestbeheer_BAO_MediweAttest::telAttestenMedewerker($contactId),
    'class' => "livePage",
  ];
```

For the *count* parameter I have used a function that counts the number of records in the table for the specific contact.